# Mocha paramterized test does not take the modified value of test data array

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, parameterized-tests

Here's the simple problem I'm struggling with. In the first example, no tests are run; whereas in the second one, two tests are run as expected.

Does not work as expected: // `testData` gets populated inside `before` here

```
// test.js
const assert = require('assert');
const forEach = require('mocha-each');

describe('compare()', () => {

    testData = [];

    before(function (done) {
        testData = [[1, 1], [2, 2]];
        done();
    });

    forEach(testData)
        .it('compares %d and %d', (baseline, actual) => {
            assert(baseline == actual);
        });

});
```

Works as expected: // `testData` is used as a hardcoded array here

```
// test.js
const assert = require('assert');
const forEach = require('mocha-each');

describe('compare()', () => {

    forEach([[1, 1], [2, 2]])
        .it('compares %d and %d', (baseline, actual) => {
            assert(baseline == actual);
        });

});
```

I do not understand why the modified value of `testData` is not taken by `it` in the first example.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with how mocha sets up the test suite.
The callback function in `before` function gets registered but does not gets executed before the mocha-each's `foreach` function.

Related issue - [Dynamically load test parameters?](https://github.com/ryym/mocha-each/issues/3)

However, to have a parameterised test, you might not need a library, a simple preloaded array would work - [Parameterized test in mocha](https://mochajs.org/#dynamically-generating-tests). Although, the difference is there is one test with multiple asserts.

[Demo - parameterized mocha tests](https://repl.it/@rvi/mocha-parameterized-tests)

Comment: As I can see, there are multiple code example in the links you have shared and I'm relatively new to Node.js, so I would really appreciate if you could tweak the non-working code I've shared in my post.